# Multiple image upload

Tags: android, image, upload

My problem is that I want to post multiple images at a time, from an Android device to a server, having the parameter format depicted in the code below, but the server only reads one of the parameters.

Note: I think the server is catching it in a foreach loop, I have no control in of the server side.

```
bab = new ByteArrayBody(data, "carpic" 
    + (Utility.upload_imageBitMap.size() - 1) + ".jpg");

Utility.reqEntity.addPart("image[]", bab);
Utility.reqEntity.addPart("image[]", bab);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Utility.reqEntity.addPart("image", bab);
```